# How to implement CircularLinkedList in Java without first & Last?

Tags: java, linked-list

A question in LinkedLists book asks to implement LinkedList without first and last pointers while allowing access to list with "current" pointer. I am not quite sure I am on the right track, any help would be appreciated. Here is what I am tried, I would like to get insert/delete working...

```
class Link
 {
    public int iData;              
    public Link next;              

 public Link(int id) // constructor
 {
  iData = id;                         
  }                          

public void displayLink()     
{
 System.out.print(iData + " ");
}
}  // end class Link


public class CircularLinkedList
{
private Link current;        
private Link first;

//-------------------------------------------------------------
public CircularLinkedList(){
 current = null; 
}

public CircularLinkedList(Link link){
current = link;
}

public Link getCurrent(){
return current;
}

public Link getNext(){
return current.next;
}

public void setCurrent(Link current){
this.current = current;
}

public void insert(int data){
Link newLink = new Link(data);

//only link
if(current == null){ 
    current = newLink;
    first = current;
}else{
    current.next = newLink;
}

newLink.next = first;
}

public void delete(){

}

public int find(int key){
return -1;
}


public void displayList()
{
Link tmp = current;
while(current != null)      // until end of list,
  {
     current.displayLink();   // print data
     current = current.next;  // move to next link
     if(current == tmp)
         break;
  }
  System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String ...args){
CircularLinkedList list = new CircularLinkedList();
list.insert(10);
list.insert(20);
list.insert(30);
list.insert(40);

list.displayList();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link class needs to set next to some value in the constructor

```
public Link (int id, Link next)
```

Then you want the list to be circular so for the first Link, next would itself. When you insert an element A, make current.next be A, and A.next be the previous value of current.next. To delete by ID search until you find it (current.next in loop) and save the previous element B each time. Then when you find element that you are searching for set B.next to B.next.next.